# R: how to get rid of or replace some elements in a column R

Tags: r, gsub

I tried to use

```
df2$y1<-gsub("*","0",as.character(df2$y1))
```

replace the * with 0 in my ip data, but it didn't work at all. Instead, it created this for the ip:

```
[665] "0201080.01010.0107060.0*0"   "0202030.08070.0109070.0*0"  
 [667] "0101040.0202010.0108030.0*0" "0101070.02060.0109080.0*0"  
 [669] "0101090.060.07040.0*0"       "0200020.0200040.04080.0*0"  
 [671] "0103070.0103020.0205000.0*0" "0103070.0103020.0205000.0*0"
```

Please help, thanks!!!

I want it looks like this:

```
1.115.193.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape the * with \\ as it is a symbol used in regex for string search patterns ("pattern" variable in gsub/grepl, etc. works using this):

First case lets replace * with 0 as you have mentioned, though the result does not look like something you seem to be expecting:

```
# first we set up the dummy data
v <- "0202030.08070.0109070.0*0"

gsub("\\*","0", v) 
[1] "0202030.08070.0109070.000"
```

What we could do is replace * and 0 though you are still missing a zero at the end:

```
gsub("\\*|0","", v) 
[1] "223.87.197."
```

So we could work it like this using a `ifelse` and `grepl`:

```
intermed <- gsub("\\*|0","", v) 
# detect if a string ends with a . (has to be escaped and $ stands for end of astring in regex)
# if found string pattern paste 0 to end of intermediate IP
ifelse(grepl(pattern = "\\.$", intermed), paste0(intermed, 0), intermed)
[1] "223.87.197.0"
```